# Settimeout works in chrome/webkit based browsers but not firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, webkit

Can somebody explain why this simple code works in webkit based browsers (even my android phone), but not on firefox?
(The code basically refreshes an iframe every 1000 ms (a bash script echos to that file))

The website for this code is http://haenh.ddns.us/ui/content/servinfo and it is embed in: http://haenh.ddns.us/ui/?page_id=2 (the first link in firefox I have to manually refresh while the second link shows the spinning green circle (showing that it is downloading content). In chrome/webkit this is refreshing as expected)

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function a(){
document.close();
document.write('<br><p align="center"><iframe src="/serv.txt" width="700" height="2000" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"<> <p>Failed</p> </iframe></p><br><br>');
setTimeout('a()', 1000);
// the old one was 15000
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="a()">
<title>ServInfo</title>
<br>

JS is required.

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `document.close()` after `document.write()` instead of before and it will solve the "always loading" issue.

---

Side notes: You can also use `setTimeout(a, 1000);` instead of `setTimeout('a()', 1000);`. Passing references is always better than using `eval` aliases.

And I assume you're aware of the terrible effects of using `document.write()` after the page has loaded, which will overwrite the page completely. I assume you're using it for that effect intentionally.